# How to make pandas python render with d3 and leaflet.js

Tags: python, d3.js, pandas, visualization

I'm a newbie desperately trying to develop a workflow between pandas in python and d3 to improve my visualisation skills. Can someone explain how to access columns of data in d3?

My effort is: http://jsbin.com/pizakerove/edit?html,output

I've managed to munge a pandas dataframe with the to_json method with the orient="index" to get into the shape I need.

I'm trying to then add the lat/long points to a leaflet.js map using d3 using Mike Bostock's tutorial - http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/

Excuse my weakness with Javascript. I understand that I need to use an accessor function to access columns of the data, but I'm completely lost how to do this.

I can see how once I can access fields of data I might be able to lever d3 to create a map and a separate bar chart.

Can someone explain what I've got wrong or at least provide a simple pathway for me to get my head around d3?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by using the 'orient' parameter of 'records' instead of 'index'.

I then used this block http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9267535 to get a working map.